# Triple (nested) if-formula Excel 2010

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Trying to work out how to set up this nested if-formula.
I've got 3 different dates, and i want the formula to pick date x first, when this is empty, get y, and if that turns up empty, get date z.

I've tried it with =IF(z2="";aa2;z2;IF(aa2="";v2;aa2)) and this gives me the error that i'm adding to much arguments.

1. Date x = cell Z2
2. Date y = cell AA2
3. Date Z = Cell V2

The reason I'm asking this question is because i keep having a hard time with these types of formula and hoping to find someone who could explain what I'm doing wrong, or that my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use

```
=IF(Z2="";IF(AA2="";V2;AA2);Z2)
```

or

```
=IF(Z2<>"";Z2;IF(AA2<>"";AA2;V2))
```

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand that my approach was wrong now. Sometimes you need that mirror in your face.